# Treating array elements as a circle

Tags: arrays, date, calendar

I don't know if the title I have chosen makes sense to all of you as it does in my head, so I'll explain.

I'm trying to come up with an ideal date mathematics solution. Got a couple of functions that convert month numbers to month names and vice versa. Imagine the situation where you want to get the previous month rather than the current and right now it's January. The array needs to jump to the last element, i.e. 12/December and also to drop the year by one.

This is what I mean by having the array elements in a circle. The element before the first one is the last one.

I'm not really sure how to start with this, or if there is something similar out there.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Nolo

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you want a Circularly Linked List:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linear_and_circular_lists

Answer (score 0):

I have written a time collecting tool **Calendar Period Collector**, which includes a similar 'time-navigation' functionality:
- select period (Year/Halfyear/Quarter/Month/Day)
- navigate to the previous, current and next period

The article [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) includes a description and the C# source code. [This](http://cpc.itenso.com/)
site provides a live Silverlight sample.

The library contains various calendar time periods with *GetNextXxx()*/*GetPreviousXxx()* methods. The implementation of a circular navigation should be an easy task (if the target period is outside of the time limit, select the time period on the opposite time limit).